# WebSphere Liberty - JWT - A JsonWebToken Principal can't be injected because one is not available

Tags: jwt, websphere-liberty, microprofile

I'm trying to implement JWT on WebSphere Liberty but am running into an error when passing in the JWT in an Authorization header.

**A JsonWebToken Principal can't be injected because one is not available. Protect the requesting resource so authentication occurs before the resource is accessed.**

The same JWT is signed with a private key and can be validated successfully on jwt.io using the public key or public cert so I don't think validity is the problem.

This is the JAXRS web resource I'm passing the JWT into:

```
import org.eclipse.microprofile.jwt.Claim;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.jwt.Claims;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.jwt.JsonWebToken;
import javax.annotation.security.PermitAll;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/jwtpoc")
@PermitAll
@RequestScoped
public class JwtPocResource {
    @Inject
    @Claim(standard = Claims.groups)
    private Set<String> groups;

    @Inject
    private JsonWebToken token;

    @GET
    public Response getOK() {
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

When GET /jwtpoc is requested I can see the "A JsonWebToken Principal can't be injected because one is not available. Protect the requesting resource so authentication occurs before the resource is accessed." in messages.log so I think it's some injection or underlying configuration is the problem.

I have my key pair set up as a pkcs#12 keyStore, public certificate stored in a pkcs#12 truststore, both are referenced by an ssl configuration and reference to ssl configuration is configured in mpJwt server.xml element. I'm using microprofile 3.2 (mpjwt-1.1).

The application class referencing JwtPocResource has:

```
import org.eclipse.microprofile.auth.LoginConfig;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@LoginConfig(authMethod = "MP-JWT")
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class JwtPocApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> services = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        services.add(JwtPocResource.class);
    }
}
```

Has anyone seen this before and can suggest a resolution?

Comment: Try to removing `@PermitAll` as this defines method without any security requirements. Also you may need to add `SecurityConstraint` in `web.xml` to protect your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for injection to happen, the resource must be protected. Per https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-jwt-auth-1.2/microprofile-jwt-auth-spec-1.2.html#_injection_of_code_jsonwebtoken_code, the injection is done for an authenticated caller.

Using @PermitAll for JAXRS will treat this resource as an unprotected resource and there will not be an authenticated caller, and the injection of the JsonWebToken will not happen.

To solve this, the resource can be protected using @RolesAllowed.

If the endpoint must use @PermitAll to handle its own authentication and authorization, then the following applies,

> If a JWT is sent to an endpoint that does not require Authentication
> and/or Authorization then it still must be verified before it can be
> accessed via JsonWebToken interface.
>
> Endpoints which need to control the authentication process themselves
> can check if a token is available by calling a
> JsonWebToken.getRawToken() method.

For 1.1, the authentication requirement applies as well per https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-jwt-auth-1.1/microprofile-jwt-auth-spec.html#_injection_of_code_jsonwebtoken_code,

> An MP-JWT implementation must support the injection of the currently
> authenticated caller as a JsonWebToken